# Error: Xenial Release repository cdrom does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, repository

New to Linux as of 5 days ago..all good just 1 issue, please help

I get this whenever i try to update using apt-get update.

```
W: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu Xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://archive.getdeb.net /ubuntu Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository '
```

Comment: It is trying to run updates from the CD-Rom you used to install. It should be using the Ubuntu repository or a local mirror. Go into System Settings, Software & Updates and untick/uncheck CD rom on first tab.

Answer (score 1):

Open the App "Software & Updates", open the tab "Other software" and un-check any items that start with `cdrom`, or relate to the repository that you receive the error for.

re-run apt-get update. that should remove the error.